# Extract Mandrill Merge Tags With Regex (star and pipe)

Tags: python, regex, django, mandrill

I am not familiar with regular expressions and I want to extract merge tags from my file. Mandrill API is using a expression like `*|first_name|*`. Also I am using it.

Assume I have a text file as below:

```
<p>*|first_name|*&nbsp;*|last_name|*</p>

<p><a href="*|campTra|*">hello</a></p>
```

I want to catch: first_name, last_name and campTra

What is the best regex to catch all these tags in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  a non-greedy regex with capturing group in `re.findall`

```
re.findall(r'\*\|(.*?)\|\*', s)
```

Comment: thank you! this is working.

Comment: Accept if this does..